# Switch or a Dictionary when assigning to new object

Tags: c#, coding-style

Recently, I've come to prefer mapping 1-1 relationships using `Dictionaries` instead of `Switch` statements. I find it to be a little faster to write and easier to mentally process. Unfortunately, when mapping to a new instance of an object, I don't want to define it like this:

```
var fooDict = new Dictionary<int, IBigObject>()
{
    { 0, new Foo() }, // Creates an instance of Foo
    { 1, new Bar() }, // Creates an instance of Bar
    { 2, new Baz() }  // Creates an instance of Baz
}

var quux = fooDict[0]; // quux references Foo
```

Given that construct, I've wasted CPU cycles and memory creating 3 objects, doing whatever their constructors might contain, and only ended up using one of them. I also believe that mapping other objects to `fooDict[0]` in this case will cause them to reference the same thing, rather than creating a new instance of `Foo` as intended. A solution would be to use a lambda instead:

```
var fooDict = new Dictionary<int, Func<IBigObject>>()
{
    { 0, () => new Foo() }, // Returns a new instance of Foo when invoked
    { 1, () => new Bar() }, // Ditto Bar
    { 2, () => new Baz() }  // Ditto Baz
}

var quux = fooDict[0](); // equivalent to saying 'var quux = new Foo();'
```

Is this getting to a point where it's too confusing? It's easy to miss that `()` on the end. Or is mapping to a function/expression a fairly common practice? The alternative would be to use a switch:

```
IBigObject quux;
switch(someInt)
{
    case 0: quux = new Foo(); break;
    case 1: quux = new Bar(); break;
    case 2: quux = new Baz(); break;
}
```

**Which invocation is more acceptable?**

- Dictionary, for faster lookups and fewer keywords (case and break)
- Switch: More commonly found in code, doesn't require the use of a
  Func<> object for indirection.

Comment: without the lambda you'll have the same instance being returned each time you do the lookup with the same key (as in `fooDict[0] is fooDict[0]`). with both the lambda and the switch this is not the case

Comment: @ratchetfreak Yes, I actually did realize this as I was typing up the example. I think I made a note of it somewhere.

Comment: I guess the fact that you explicitely put it in a Constant mean that you need the created object to be mutable. But if one day you can make them immutable, then returning the object directly will be the best solution. You can put the dict in a const field and only incur the cost of creation once in the whole application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's an interesting take on the [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern).  I like the combination of the Dictionary and the lambda expression; it made me look at that container in a new way.

I'm ignoring the concern in your question about CPU cycles as you mentioned in the comments that the non-lambda approach doesn't provide what you need.

I think either approach (switch vs. Dictionary + lambda) is going to be fine.  The only limitation is that by using the Dictionary, you are limiting the types of inputs you could receive in order to generate the returned class.

Using a switch statement would provide you more flexibility on input parameters.  However, if this got to be an issue, you could wrap the Dictionary inside of a method and have the same end result.

If it's new for your team, comment the code and explain what's going on.  Call for a team code review, walk them through what was done and make them aware of it.  Other than that, it looks fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, as of about a month ago, my team consists solely of me (the lead quit). I didn't think of its relevance to the factory pattern. That's a neat observation, actually.

Comment: @KChaloux: Of course, if you were using just the Factory Method pattern, your `case 0: quux = new Foo(); break;` becomes `case 0: return new Foo();` which is frankly as easy to write and much easier to read than `{ 0, () => new Foo() }`

Comment: @pdr That's shown up a few places in code already. There's probably a good reason to create a factory method on the object that inspired this question, but I figured it was interesting enough to ask on its own.

Comment: @KChaloux: I confess I'm not keen on the recent obsession with replacing switch/case with a dictionary. I've not seen a case yet where simplifying and isolating the switch in its own method wouldn't have been more effective.

Comment: @pdr Obsession is a **strong** word to use here. More of a consideration when deciding how to deal with one-off mappings between values. I agree that in cases where it's repeated, its best to isolate a creational method.

Comment: @KChaloux: Sorry, not accusing you personally of obsession, but this comes up a lot on this site as an example of how not to have switches, cause "switches are evil, etc." But as far as I'm concerned, it's still a switch with a less-intuitive syntax (http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/146771/can-the-strategy-pattern-be-implemented-without-significant-branching) If language creators simply replaced switch with foo and case with bar, it wouldn't become a better practice, just cause Martin Fowler said switches, specifically, are a code smell.

Comment: What do you mean, using a `switch` provides more flexibility on inputs? Switch can be used only with a very limited range of types (built-in integral types, `string`, `enum`s and few other types), while `Dictionary` can be used with anything that correctly implements `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()`.

Comment: @svick - what I was referring to was that the Dictionary is fixed to a built in type whereas a method could receive an object, examine it, and then create based upon what it found.  With the dictionary, the caller must know what it's looking for.  Using a method + switch allows you to abstract out the interface into the factory.  But it's not like that's a major point of concern in this case.

Answer (score 7):

C# 4.0 gives you the [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331) class, which is similar to your own second solution, but shouts out "Lazy initialization" more explicitly.

```
var fooDict = new Dictionary<int, Lazy<IBigObject>>()
{
    { 0, new Lazy(() => new Foo()) }, // Returns a new instance of Foo when invoked
    { 1, new Lazy(() => new Bar()) }, // Ditto Bar
    { 2, new Lazy(() => new Baz()) }  // Ditto Baz
}
```

Comment: Ooh, I didn't know that.

Comment: Oh, that's nice!

Comment: However, once Lazy.Value is invoked, it uses the same instance for its lifetime.  See [Lazy Initialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997286(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Of course, otherwise it wouldn't be lazy initialization, just re-initialization every time.

Comment: The OP states that he needs it to create new instances each time.  The second solution with lambdas and the third solution with a switch both do that, while the first solution and the Lazy<T> implementation do not.

Comment: You're right. I didn't notice that in the OP, since it's such a less-useful use-case, in my experience. :)

Answer (score 2):

Stylistically I think the readability is equal between them. It's easier to do dependency injection with the `Dictionary`.

Don't forget that you must check whether the key exists when using the `Dictionary`, and must provide a fallback if it does not.

I would prefer the `switch` statement for static code paths, and the `Dictionary` for dynamic code paths (where you might add or remove entries). The compiler might be able to perform some static optimizations with the `switch` that it cannot with the `Dictionary`.

Interestingly, this `Dictionary` pattern is what people sometimes do in Python, because Python lacks the `switch` statement. Otherwise they use if-else chains.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I would prefer neither.

Whatever is consuming this should work with a `Func<int, IBigObject>`. Then the source of your mapping can be a Dictionary or a method that has a switch statement or a web service call or some file lookup... whatever.

As for implementation, I'd prefer the Dictionary since that is more easily refactored from 'hard code dictionary, lookup key, return result' to 'load dictionary from file, lookup key, return result'.